# How to get text from a dynamic label id HTML field using its relative xpath in Katalon?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gettext, katalon-studio, katalon

[Error received while using the xpath of the dynamic element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pHDf.png)I want to fetch the details of login failure from a website to the katalon console.
Now, the problem i am facing while doing this is that, katalon cannot find the element by the id of the element because the id is dynamically changing. Hence i am using xpath to solve that problem. But while fetching a text on the website it cannot capture that element with a level tag.

[On Clicking the login button thios error appears and then this error should be fetched by Katalon into its own console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e54sw.png)
[This is code used to fetch the details of the login error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXEKS.png)
[Which printing the variable data 1, i am not able to receive any kind of data in the Katalon log viewer or in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSsJ0.png)

If anyone one could help me on this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the above problem is to create customized xpaths for all elements which needs to be captured. For example:
Creating an xpath for the Ask Question button above.
//a[@class="ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary"]

To learn more about how to create unique customized xpaths for all types of element, please watch this video:(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uktjWgKrtI).

I think xpaths are a very usefull tool to access any kind of elements present in any website.

To use the xpaths in katalon by using Selenium drivers :
Package files :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By as By
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys as Keys
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver as WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement as WebElement
```

Code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('a[@class="ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary')).click()
```